# Errno 13 Permission denied (exception: _SystemExceptionFromAppError(e)) when trying to send mail on app engine using python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a server on app engine from which I'm trying to send a mail with an SMTP socket. The code goes something like this:

```
session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
session.starttls()
session.ehlo()
session.login(sender, sender_password) 
session.sendmail(sender, recipient, msg.as_string())
session.quit()
```

and I get the error in the title on the line for "session.starttls()".

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Were you ever able to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine does not permit apps to send mail directly.  Use the [AppEngine Mail Python API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/) instead.

Comment: I'm trying to send the mail via smtp.gmail.com on port 587. It's not supposed to be blocked (as it is on a whitelist).

Comment: Is the value of SMTP_PORT equal to 587?  Can you log it?

Comment: It's hard coded a few lines before:
    SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    SMTP_PORT = 587

Comment: Hmm, [AppEngine Socket Python API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/) has an example SMTP call with a third parameter "mymailhostname".  And it says sockets are available only for paid apps.

Comment: I enabled billing on my app… I think it some sort of configuration I'm missing.